Angular frontend C# Backend Authentication with F5 Issues
I am kind of lost here.
Our company is only using F5 for user authentication and currently f5 is generating OAuth Bearer that is consumed by the backend applications. This process is works well with in C#/Razor applications.
However, we have decided to move away from Razor and we build the SPA application using Angular and .Net 8.
Currently, we are facing big issue when it comes to Authenticating users, It is done through F5/webtop and then f5 sends the token to the backend of the application.
Please note our f5 does not have openid set up properly and company have strict policies about authentication.
I have attached a sequence diagram what needs to be done. This sequence diagram is not 100% correct.
For instance, I think I need to send the token back to the frontend after authenticating, so the angular guards would function properly. please note that we do not have login page for angular frontend.
Here is a diagram showing our auth flow
I tried creating VS version of Angular project and try not to load the front end if there are no authentication, That did not work.
Second approach is I can still load the frontend but if there are no token, it will redirect it to unauthorized page, But I am not sure how to pass the token from backend to frontend.

If the request should be sent with outgoing credentials (cookies) you need add withCredentials
For this, use an interceptor in the way
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, handler: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (not_required_authentication) //<--check when it's necessary or not
      return handler.handle(req);

    const nextReq = req.clone({
      url: req.url,
      withCredentials: true //<--this

    });
    return handler.handle(nextReq);
   
  }

